# Accessing the microphone level in Windows with C#

Tags: c#, audio, microphone

due to the fact that some applications (games) set the microphone level of my device to a value of 100%, I would like to control this value in an C# application and adjust it if necessary.

[image: this value is meant]

Do you have an idea how I can access and adjust this value? winmm.dll seems to be the answer, but I couldn't find how to get the level of an audio device...

**Edit:** To make that clear, I don't want to change the applications volume level, I have to change the level of the primary microphone...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change program's volume on Win 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284913/change-programs-volume-on-win-7)

Comment: Please use Google first, most obvious query is "c# change microphone level".  All the top hits are SO questions, we don't need another one.